# Subtraction of reversed digits with recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, digits, subtraction

i'm trying to do a subtraction of digits in a recursive way, lets say that I have the number 125 then the subtraction takes place doing it this way

```
    5-2-1 = 2
```

I've already done the sum with recursion but i'm stuck thinking about it because i'm trying to get each digit and then subtract it within the function itself this way

```
int RecursiveMath::restaDigitos(int n){


   if(n/10 <= 1){
      return 0;
   }else{
    return restaDigitos(n/10) - n%10;
   }

}
```

I do know this function is not working but it's what i've tried along with many combinations, I feel like i'm complicating it too much, any help/advice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the task because `5 - 2 - 1` is equal to `5 - (2 + 1)`, so we can sum up all digits except highest, and subtract this sum from it.

```
int subtractDigits(const unsigned int n, const bool first = true){
    if(n == 0){
         return 0;
    }

    if(first){
        return n % 10 - subtractDigits(n / 10, false);
    }
    else{
        return n % 10 + subtractDigits(n / 10, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've already tried that but it's a non-recursive solution, I'm trying to do it with recursion

Comment: @NeptaliD wait a minute, I'll try to make recursive version

Comment: @LibertyPaul For `125` this outputs `-6`

Comment: Well this one is nice... but computes 1 - 2 - 5 = -6 for input 125 when OP wanted 5 - 2 - 1 = 2 ;-)

Comment: Fixed, now it should return corect answer.

Comment: The function is fully recursive -> never stops

Comment: Damn i've just came back! this is working thank you so much, I can see what you did there and it is totally awesome! i'm just starting to learn recursion so this is pretty neat how you achieved it!

Answer (score 0):

AHHH This one was tricky

```
#include <stdio.h>
int restaDigitos(int n){
    printf("Processing: %d\n", n);
    printf("division: %d\n", n/10);
    if(n==0){
        return 0;
    }else{
        return  n%10 + restaDigitos(n/10);
    }
}

int main() {
    int input = 125;
    int firstVal = input % 10;

    int result = restaDigitos(input / 10);
    printf("result: %d\n", firstVal - result);
}
```

Two major corrections were made:

1. Your termination condition was neglecting the last case where a single digit remains so it terminated early
2. The first value cannot be recursive because it is positive. (5-2-1) -> The first number 5 is positive whereas the other values are negative

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are also subtracting the last number (0 - 1 -2 - 5), but from what I can tell from your question, you want to add it (0 - 1 -2 + 5). My solution is to add another argument specifying the number of digits so that you know when to add instead of subtract

```
int RecursiveMath::restaDigitos(int n, int numDigits){
    if (n ==  0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n / (pow(10, numDigits - 1)) >= 1){
        return restaDigitos(n/10, numDigits) + n % 10;
    } else {
    return restaDigitos(n / 10, numDigits) - n % 10;
   }
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, the pow() will cast int to double. It is so uneffective!

Answer (score 0):

You are processing the first value differently that the others. Such a use case leads to tricky recursion ways, using default parameters or static values for one shot solutions.

Here you could use:

```
int restaDigitos(int val, bool first = true, int curr = 0) {
    if (val == 0) return curr;
    if (first) curr = val%10;
    else curr -= val%10;
    return restaDigitos(val/10, false, curr);
}
```

You can control that `restaDigitos(125);` gives as expected 2.

Comment: It's redundant to pass `bool first` flag. You can check it by dividing by 10.